dnsmasq not block google.com subdomains
dnsmasq installed on my server and has the following configuration:
no-hosts
no-resolv 

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
server=/google.com/127.0.0.1
address=/google.com/127.0.0.1
server=/*.google.com/#

but when I try to check with the utility DIG I get the following response:
dig @127.0.0.1 mail.google.com
mail.google.com.        0       IN      A       127.0.0.1

dig @127.0.0.1 google.com
google.com.             0       IN      A       127.0.0.1

why does mail.google.com it output 127.0.0.1 if there is a rule server=/*.google.com/#  ?

If you want to block all Google subdomains except for Gmail you need this dnsmasq configuration
address=/google.com/0.0.0.0
address=/mail.google.com/#

But this is a bad idea! Because GMail uses other Google subdomains to load resources. If you block them that may cause unexpected behaviors.
Note:
This config line server=/*.google.com/# is invalid because dnsmasq requires specific address entries for each subdomain.
